# Backwards Compatibility from SSIS Packages

Tags: ssis, package, compatibility, sql-server-2016-express

We have two SQL Servers, one is our testing Server and the other our live Server.

We want upgrade the live Server to SQL Server 2016. We have SQL Server 2012 on both servers at the moment.

So my questions is: Is it possible to have as Data Source SQL Server 2016 and as Destination SQL Server 2012 in SSIS Packages? Or are there other problems?

Comment: Your prelude and question don't match?  Are you using SSIS to move data from your test server to your live or are you asking if you can deploy the same packages to both your test and live server if they are different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: The SSIS service version has nothing to do with how SSIS connects to it. It's the OLEDB or ADO.NET provider that actually connects and loads the data. You could connect to 2016 even from SSIS 2008 R2 or earlier and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have an SSIS package use SQL 2016 as a Data Source and SQL 2012 as the Destination.   Just be sure to choose the correct provider when setting up the connection for each.

And actually, it looks like both 2016 and 2012 use the same provider (SQLNCLI11) so there should be no problem.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But can you explain "use the correct connection string for each" a litte bit more detailed?

Thanks :)